# What are the top artificial intelligence journals?

Tags: research

What are the top artificial intelligence journals?

I am looking for general artificial intelligence research, not necessarily machine learning.

Answer (score 4):

This [link](http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=1702) includes various journals for artificial intelligence applied to various domains.

Some of those are:

1. IEEE Transactions on Human-Machine Systems
2. Journal of the ACM
3. Knowledge-based systems
4. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence
5. Journal of Memory and Language.

There are many more. You can refer to any of those journals and explore the research done by AI enthusiasts and researchers.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of others:

- [Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research (JAIR)](http://jair.org)
- IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering
- IEEE Computational Intelligence Magazine

Answer (score 2):

I most often reference:

http://dblp.uni-trier.de/

It's not a journal but it gets me where I need to go.

Answer (score 2):

The journal "Artificial Intelligence (AI)" (https://www.journals.elsevier.com/artificial-intelligence/) was not listed, yet, although being considered *the* top-level journal on AI. Although this is a journal for AI (just being named "Artificial Intelligence"), it is not to be confused with another top-level AI journal, called "Journal on Artificial Intelligence Research (JAIR)" (http://www.jair.org/), which was already listed in one of the other answers.

Further, there is a German Journal on AI, called "KI - Künstliche Intelligenz" (German for AI), but almost always the articles are in English as well (http://www.kuenstliche-intelligenz.de/en/ki-journal/). While being internationally recognized, it is not regarded a top-level journal. A nice feature of that journal is that every special issue has an editorial (a special "article" at the beginning of each journal), in which there is a section called "service". This service section lists publication media (like journals) and conferences etc. that are related to the given special issue. So, in case you are interested in journals of a special field of AI (like human-computer interaction), just search for a special issue that is related to that topic and read the editorial's service part.